# Picture loading slowly on product page

Tags: product, magento2.3, product-images, porto-theme

I am using Magento 2.3.0 and Porto theme. On my product page, the image is loading very slowly. How can I load it fast?

Answer (score 1):

If product images are large size, You can resize image by running below command.

```
php <magento install dir>/bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

**Source:** http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-images.html#resize-catalog-images

Comment: I appreciate but it is not working for me.